# How to convert a map to json where one of the types is AnyRef

Tags: json, scala, elasticsearch, play-json

I have a Map which is of the type `[String, AnyRef]`. How do i convert it to Json using play-json. I found some answers but they all had a type defined. When i tried converting i got the compiler error message as:

> No implicit arguments of type: Writes[Map[String, AnyRef]]

```
val testMap: Map[String, AnyRef] = Map.empty[String, AnyRef]
```

Suppose this map has the following data:

```
{ "lastModifiedTime" -> 1575311400000,
    "user_id" -> 1,
    "user_email" -> "user@email.com",
    "is_active" -> true,
    "project_id" -> 1,
    "status"-> "COMPLETED" }
```

So my question is if I have AnyRef as the second type in map how will I convert it to Json using just play-Json ?

Correction => 
This map is obtained as a result of elastic search result, so i cannot guarantee that every time the map will be same, but it will be of the same type that is, Map[String, AnyRef].

Answer (score 3):

Play-json try to be as typesafe as possible and this means it cannot provide implicitly serializer for `Map[String, AnyRef]`. It could shadow other serializers and it couldn't ensure it will not fail. You can create your own but it'll be hard-coded and you should not put it in your globals:

```scala
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
import play.api.libs.json._

val testMap = Map[String,Any](
  "test" -> 1, 
  "otherTest" -> "denada",
  "mapsAlsoWorksSomehow" -> Map (
    "wee" -> true,
    "mapsEverywhere" -> Map (
       "wee" -> false, "prr" -> new java.util.Date(),
    ),
    "ops" -> new java.lang.Integer(22) 
  )
)

//you can create your own function that just maps objects to JsValues without using types...
//not safe but works
def toJsValue(a:Any):JsValue = a match {
  case v:JsValue => v
  case v:Map[String,_] => JsObject(v.map { case (k,v) => (k, toJsValue(v)) }) //keep in mind we assume this is map of [String,Any] if not it will blow up :(
  case v:String => JsString(v)
  case v:Int => JsNumber(v)
  case v:Boolean => JsBoolean(v)
  case v:java.util.Date => JsString(v.toString)
  case v if v == null => JsNull
}

implicit lazy val anyWriter:Writes[Map[String,Any]] = new Writes[Map[String,Any]] {
  def writes(a:Map[String,Any]):JsValue = toJsValue(a)
}


println(Json.toJson(testMap))
println(toJsValue(testMap))

//here we use anyWriter implicitly but there is other one... currently shadowed :(.
println(Json.toJson(testMap.mapValues[JsValue] { case (v) => toJsValue(v) }))
```

But keep in mind that it will blow up when You will have unsupported type in Map. I guess best way is not to create implicit writer but use `toJsValue` method on arguments of a map and then try to serialize it (like in last `println`).

[demo](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WwH6XB8/3)

If it was helpful, up-vote please and mark as answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am trying to fetch results from Elastic search which will not return the exact number of elements inside the map once the search fails. Sorry i forgot to add this in my question

Comment: It doesn't matter I guess. More important is to support all possible types you have.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to convert all the values to `String` and save that.

```
val stringMap = testMap.mapValues(_.toString)
```

Failing that you either have to create a custom handler for `AnyRef` or manually create a `JObject` from the `Map` and use `match` to select the specific JSON type for each element.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

The closest thing to `AnyRef` you can have is `play.api.libs.json.JsValue`.

Or in other words you need a `JSON`-like object structure, where you have *Writers*, resp. *Readers*.

Let me know if you need further explanation.